# Laravel Artisan command is not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I Have installed PHP7.1 earlier. Then I downgraded to 5.6.
Now Laravel Artisan command is not working.The error is

```
command not found...
```

and also `php -v`is not working either. instead of `php -v`  , `php56 -v` is working. 
I'm using Fedora 26 , Laravel version is v5.0

Comment: On what system did you install PHP? Could you be more specific? What error are you getting?

Comment: Can you show error here?

Comment: try php56 artisan

Comment: @akbansa question edited . Please do check.

Comment: so, `php56 artisan` instead of `php artisan`
Alternatively, you could try to to `ln -s /usr/local/bin/php56 /usr/local/bin/php` (I assume here your binary is in /usr/local/bin, you can do `whereis php56` to find the path )

Comment: I used php56 artisan, but it throwed the below error.
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\mb_internal_encoding() in /mnt/sda6/example.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php on line 43
'

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your default php version on terminal : `update-alternatives --config php`

This will provide you php options available to select the preferred one.

Answer (score 0):

**Switch PHP version:**

**From php5.6 to php7.0:**

Apache:

```
sudo a2dismod php5.6 ; sudo a2enmod php7.0 ; sudo service apache2 restart
```

CLI:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.0
```

**From php7.0 to php5.6:**

Apache:

```
sudo a2dismod php7.0 ; sudo a2enmod php5.6 ; sudo service apache2 restart
```

CLI:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6
```